# how to pause sequential transition of JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, transition

Code below show part of the function of my sequential transition,i wish to use **Pslideshow.pause()** to enable user to pause the slide and also  continue play the slide.

But i realised, once i use **Pslideshow.play()** , the status of the Pslideshow change into Stopped immediately when i clicked on the pane which i create to display the slide.

What should i do in order to allow user to pause and play again my sequential transition? Thanks in advance!

```
public void start(){
for (Label slide : LabelSlides) {

    SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();
    FadeTransition fadeIn = getFadeTransition(slide, 0.0, 1.0, 2000);
    PauseTransition stayOn = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(2000));
    FadeTransition fadeOut = getFadeTransition(slide, 1.0, 0.0, 2000); 

    sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(fadeIn, stayOn, fadeOut);
    slide.setOpacity(0);
    this.root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Black");
    this.root.getChildren().add(slide);
    Pslideshow.getChildren().add(sequentialTransition); 
    }

    Pslideshow.play();
}

@FXML 
public void PlaySlide(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{   Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
    Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
    Stage newStage = new Stage();
    newStage.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
    newStage.setHeight(stage.getHeight());
    Scene_3Controller simpleSlideShow = new Scene_3Controller();      
    Scene scene = new Scene(simpleSlideShow.getRoot());
    MediaP.play();
    simpleSlideShow.start();       
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new ClickHandler());      
    newStage.setScene(scene);
    newStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Does your next slide wait for user input?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha No, i stored my images in LabelSlides[ ], i just retrieve from db

Comment: I should have been clear while asking the question. When you say "`Pslideshow.play()` changes the status of the Pslideshow change into Stopped immediately". I am not really sure that should be happening, how exactly are you checking the status?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Oh ic, i added in a system output to show the status of the Pslideshow. In `start ()` method, status output as **running**, then in `PlaySlide(Action)` method, it output as **stopped**, and i did add a click handler, `scene.setOnMouseClicked(new ClickHandler());`  it showing Stopped also when i clicked on the slide.

Comment: Can you try using [this example](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/6be32dd48e52f7df3cdb9a15fd482ec0) and comment back which part doesn't fit in your implementation ? It shows how we play, pause a ST even after the status has been changed to STOPPED.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha OK thank i will try it out and come back to you ^^

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i not sure is it the setOnAction part is the cause of my error, what if i wanted to allow user clicked on the scene instead of button for pause and play action?

Comment: An event handler shouldn't be a reason for this. It must be the logic inside it. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  would be of great help.

Comment: i found the error! it was sth wrong with this part, but i dunno why . 
`Scene_3Controller simpleSlideShow = new Scene_3Controller();      
    Scene scene = new Scene(simpleSlideShow.getRoot());` 
Right now i straight declare a new scene like you did, then it works. 
Thanks anyway, at least it is fixed ;)

Comment: I will add the MCVE as an answer to help someone looking for similar issues.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code is copied from the [SequentialTransitionStatus](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/6be32dd48e52f7df3cdb9a15fd482ec0)  gist that I created to explain how SequentialTransition can change different status i.e. RUNNING, PAUSED, STOPPED.

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SequentialTransitionStatus extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label slide = new Label("slide");
        slide.setOpacity(0);

        FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(2000), slide);
        fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeIn.setToValue(1);
        PauseTransition stayOn = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(1000));
        FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(2000), slide);
        fadeOut.setFromValue(1);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0);
        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();
        sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(fadeIn, stayOn, fadeOut);

        Label status = new Label();
        status.textProperty().bind(sequentialTransition.statusProperty().asString());

        Button play = new Button("Play");
        play.setOnAction(event -> sequentialTransition.play());

        Button pause = new Button("Pause");
        pause.setOnAction(event -> sequentialTransition.pause());

        HBox hBox = new HBox(10, play, pause);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        VBox box = new VBox(20, slide, hBox, status);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```